# Property does not exist on type "Interface | undefined"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-typescript, type-assertion

I have this context

```
export type SearchBooleanContextInterface = {
    isSearched: IsSearched,
    setIsSearched?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<IsSearched>>
}
export interface SearchPageContextInterface{
    value: string,
    payload: any,
    searchBoolean: SearchBooleanContextInterface
}
export const SearchPageContext = createContext<Partial<SearchPageContextInterface>>({});
```

I define the value here:

```
<SearchPageContext.Provider value={{value: "", payload: "", searchBoolean: {isSearched, setIsSearched}}}>
```

But when I want to use the context and then destructure "seachBoolean" property like this:

```
 const SearchPage = useContext(SearchPageContext);
 const {searchBoolean} = SearchPage;
 const {isSearched} = searchBoolean;
```

it returns this error message Property 'isSearched' does not exist on type 'SearchBooleanContextInterface | undefined'.

To my understanding, I should have typed the property in earlier interface, so why am I getting this error?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: because of `Partial`

Answer (score 0):

`createContext`'s generic type is set to be `Partial<SearchPageContextInterface>`. This means that every variable in `SearchPageContextInterface` will be optional. As such, the compiler infers `searchBoolean`'s type to be `SearchBooleanContextInterface | undefined`.

While `SearchBooleanContextInterface` contains `isSearched`, `undefined` obviously does not, which causes the compiler to return the error.

You could either swap `Partial<SearchPageContextInterface>` with `SearchPageContextInterface`, or change your code to something to the lines of

```
const SearchPage = useContext(SearchPageContext);
const {searchBoolean} = SearchPage;
const isSearched = searchBoolean?.isSearched;
if(isSearched === undefined) {
    // What would you like to do if `isSearch` is not defined?
} else {
    // `isSearched` is properly defined. Continue as expected.
}
```